# Miracast between android mobile

Tags: android, miracast

I am trying to develop a Miracast application that mirrors main user screen on other's screen. I am trying this by using WiFi-Hotspots. Is this possible with WiFi-Direct? If possible, please give some hints.

Answer (score 0):

Miracast employs the peer-to-peer Wi-Fi Direct standard. So yes you can directly use Wi-fi Direct. If you're trying to do this on Android, you can check WiFi P2P connections.

[WiFi P2P connection](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html)

P.S. If you're developing an android application, check Presentation and MediaRouter:

[Presentation class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation.html)

[MediaRouter](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarouter.html#media-route-button)

Answer (score -1):

According to specs, Miracast uses WiFi-Direct connections exclusively. So the hint I can provide is: buy the Miracast specs document.